# Using rect and mask simultaneously in OpenCV Grabcut python

Tags: python, opencv, shapely

I'm using OpenCV 3 alpha in Python on Windows. I have a background subtraction method that leads into image segmentation using grabcut. So i have MOG detector that gives me some information on likely foreground and background. So for example here is the current image (rect just given for visualization).

[image: Input image]

And here is the output from the MOG detector.

[image]

I want to feed this information into cv2.grabcut. My hope is that i don't need to segment the entire image, and that it will be faster (?) to specify a region around the known object and pass likely foreground and background. The blobs are stored as shapely polygons, whose bounds are xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax

> 

```
#expand the bounding box of the polygons about 5 times
b=blob.buffer(50).bounds

#change to integer
rect=[int(x) for x in b]

#Shapely give coordinates in xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax

#Format into x,y,w,h required by grabcut in opencv
rectf=tuple([rect[0],rect[1],rect[2]-rect[0],rect[3]-rect[1]])                                                 

#create a mask
mask = np.zeros(grabCUTimage.shape[:2],np.uint8)

#Make anywhere black in the grey_image (output from MOG) as likely background
#Make anywhere white in the grey_image (output from MOG) as definite foreground
mask[grey_image == 0] = 2
mask[grey_image == 255] = 1    

#Make containers                                
bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)                        

#Run grabcut
cv2.grabCut(grabCUTimage,mask,rectf,bgdModel,fgdModel,4,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

#Multiple new mask by original image to get cut            
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
cGB =grabCUTimage*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]
```

This always gives me a black image. all background.

When i initialize with cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK it works correctly (please ignore the red square). However it definitely ignores the rect, because sometimes it includes estimated foreground well outside the rect boundaries (not shown in this case).

[image]

Am i storing the rect wrong? Is it not x,y,w,h? Will specifying a rect actually make it faster or should i crop the image?

Comment: Given that you have a rough idea about the bounding box, why don't you just crop the entire image to a smaller region and use grabCut there? This should surely speed up the algorithm and it might even be advantageous since it is not distracted by background far away from the object you like to isolate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but when you use "GC_Init_with_Rect" in Grabcut its better to initialize the whole mask and set it to "probably Background":

```
mask = Mat::ones(image.size(), CV_8UC1) * GC_PR_BGD; //GC_PR_BGD
```

its C++ but I think you get the idea.

update 1:
I don't think that this is faster, but when you use your MOG information to draw a bigger rectangle around your ROI you can set the outside of the rectangle to GC_BGD. This should be faster.

Comment: I'm making this as a solution, because it does work, but just for readers information, it still doesn't speed up grabcut very much. I'm glad it works though.

Answer (score 0):

I can see this is an old question but I was working on it some days now and it seems there is  a mistake in the rectangle definition. I defined my parameters as (x,y,**h**,**w**) and it worked beautifully for me.

Hope it helps.